# Change BASE_DIR in django settings to up a directory

Tags: django, django-settings

I am working on django project in which I tried to setup multiple settings files and now I am getting database migrations error/notification .I dont want to create new db and use the previous one .
**Previous dir Structure**

```
|myproject
|-myproject
|--settings.py
|-db
```

and in my base.py `BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent` 

**Current Dir**

```
|myproject
|-myproject
|--db(new db after running sever)
|--settings
|---base.py
|---development.py
|-db(old db)
```

I dont how base_dir thing works .I want to use my old db and all other stuff .I tried google but I dont understand anything there.so how to I up one dir my BASE_DIR path .

Thanks in advance any advice will be helpful.

Comment: @djvg it worked can you explain a little bit what is happening here and thanks

Comment: See `pathlib` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent). It has examples.

Comment: show me the error of migration

Comment: @ManojTolagekar : it was basic error **You have 31 unapplied migrations** and **static  directory doesnt exists** but its fixed now

Comment: then what's the problem